# Combine two elements from different lists into a coordinate tuple

Tags: python, list

So I have these tuples in two lists in another tuple which look like

```
data_tuple = ([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)(7,8,9)],[(a,b,c),(d,e,f)(g,h,i)])
```

I want to build a set of coordinates using the corresponding indexed elements from each list, so that it looks like

```
final = [(2,b),(5,e),(8,h)]
```

Here's what I got:

```
for a in data_tuple[0]:
    x = a[1]
    for b in data_tuple[1]:
        y = b[1]
        print(x,y)
```

For now I just wanna check if my iteration/indentation is right so I don't need to put them in a list just yet. Right now the outcome for this particular code is

```
(2,b)
(2,e)
(2,h)
(5,b)
(5,e)
```

and so on until it reaches (8,h).

If I bring my print line to the left, under the second for loop, I get

```
(2,h)
(5,h)
(8,h)
```

How do I fix this? Sorry if I don't make any sense =/. As you can tell I'm extremely new to Python so I'm not familiar with a lot of import modules. Any help please?

Comment: What should the final set of data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> print [(i[0][1],i[1][1]) for i in zip(*data_tuple)]
[(2, 'b'), (5, 'e'), (8, 'h')]
```

but often clarity is more important than brevity

I dont really understand your original question since it looks like its working as intended that implies your indentation and iteration is fine..

[edit] this is what you want i think

```
for i in range(len(data_tuple[0]):
    x,y = data_tuple[0][i][1],data_tuple[1][i][1],
    print (x,y)
```

or

```
>>> for numbr,letr in zip(*data_tuple):
...     x,y = numbr[1],letr[1]
...     print(x,y)
...
```

Comment: I edited my question since I don't know how to insert coding into comments #noob. =/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> data_tuple = ([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)],[("a","b","c"),("d","e","f"),("g","h","i")])
>>> full_numbers_list, full_letters_list = data_tuple
>>> desired_output_idx = (1,)
>>>
>>> results = []
>>> for numbers, letters in zip(full_numbers_list, full_letters_list):
...     assert len(numbers) == len(letters) # make sure assumption is met
...     for i in range(len(numbers)): 
...         if i in desired_output_idx:
...             results.append((numbers[i], letters[i]))
...
>>> results
[(2, 'b'), (5, 'e'), (8, 'h')]
```

In place of using the steps of unpacking `data_tuple` you can use `*data_tuple` which will unpack your tuple for input to the `zip()` function.

```
>>> zip(*data_tuple)
[((1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')), ((4, 5, 6), ('d', 'e', 'f')), ((7, 8, 9), ('g', 'h', 'i'))]
>>>
>>> # *data_tuple is the same as:
>>> numbers, letters = data_tuple
>>> zip(numbers, letters)
[((1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')), ((4, 5, 6), ('d', 'e', 'f')), ((7, 8, 9), ('g', 'h', 'i'))]
```

Comment: I've edited the question so that it's clearer..but I don't know how zip works, mind explaining?

Comment: `zip()` zips two lists together: `zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) -> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`

Comment: And *data_tuple just unpacks the data_tuple so you're giving zip two separate lists.  numbers, letters = data_tuple;zip(numbers, letters) has the same effect.  I'll update to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want the second element:

```
[ (a, b) for ((_,a,_), (_,b,_)) in zip(*data_tuple) ]
```

Note that this produces the result you indicated, but isn't the same as your algorithm, which would produce the cartesian product. This would be achieved thus:

```
[ (a, b)
  for (_,a,_) in data_tuple[0]
  for (_,b,_) in data_tuple[1] ]
```

Assuming you always want the second element:

```
[ (a, b) for ((_,a,_), (_,b,_)) in zip(*data_tuple) ]
```

Note that this produces the result you indicated, but isn't the same as your algorithm, which would produce the cartesian product. This would be achieved thus:

```
[ (a, b)
  for (_,a,_) in data_tuple[0]
  for (_,b,_) in data_tuple[1] ]
```

**EDIT:** In response to your comment, here's the session I ran:

```
>>> [ (a, b)
...   for (_,a,_) in data_tuple[0]
...   for (_,b,_) in data_tuple[1] ]
[(2, 'b'), (2, 'e'), (2, 'h'), (5, 'b'), (5, 'e'), (5, 'h'), (8, 'b'), (8, 'e'), (8, 'h')]
```

This is the cartesian product, as per your original code.

Based on your amended question, however, I'm pretty sure you just want the first code I presented:

```
>>> [ (a, b) for ((_,a,_), (_,b,_)) in zip(*data_tuple) ]
[(2, 'b'), (5, 'e'), (8, 'h')]
```

Comment: I assigned your 2nd code to a variable and printed that variable; what came out was a long, long list of tuple with the <a> bit repeated with each <b> (like my first output mentioned above) =S

Comment: @user1632262: I'm not sure what you mean by "long, long list…". I've amended my answer to show that the output is the cartesian product, which is a mere 9 elements.